# How to search image which image name contain '12345' in textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, windows-forms-designer

I'm a newbie in C# programming language. I need some guide on how can I search image in textbox which just typing image name that contain **12345**. This is because each image name in my folder is naming like this > **JUN (12345)**. I want the image display at picturebox after typing **12345** in textbox. Here is my code that I already try it not display image that contain **12345**. Hope anyone can help me. Thanks

```
  private void textBoxWorkNo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                    {
                        if (textBoxWorkNo.Text != "")
                        {
                            //Do something
                            string selectSql = "select name, empno, icnum, passport, deptno, section, designation from m_employee where workno=@workno";
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workno", textBoxWorkNo.Text);

                            bool isDataFound = false;

                            try
                            {
                                con.Open();

                                using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                                {

                                while (read.Read())
                                {
                                    isDataFound = true;

                                    textBoxEmplNo.Text = (read["empno"].ToString());
                                    textBoxName.Text = (read["name"].ToString());
                                    textBoxICPass.Text = (read["icnum"].ToString());
                                    textBoxPassport.Text = (read["passport"].ToString());
                                    textBoxDept.Text = (read["deptno"].ToString());
                                    textBoxSection.Text = (read["section"].ToString());
                                    textBoxDesignation.Text = (read["designation"].ToString());


                                    //BaseFolder that contains the multiple folders 
                                    //If the folders don't share the same base folder make an array with full paths
                                    string baseFolder = "C:\\Users\\hamizah\\Desktop\\photo";
                            string[] employeeFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(baseFolder);


                                    //Search image
                                    string imgName = "%'" + textBoxEmplNo.Text + "%'" + ".jpg";

                                    //Bool to see if file is found after checking all
                                    bool fileFound = false;

                                    foreach (var folderName in employeeFolders)
                                    {
                                        var path = Path.Combine(folderName, imgName);
                                        if (File.Exists(path))
                                        {
                                            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                                            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
                                            fileFound = true;
                                            //If you want to stop looking, break; here 
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (!fileFound)
                                    {
                                        //Display message that No such image found
                                        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                                        pictureBox1.Image = 

     Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\hamizah\Desktop\images\photo\No-image-found.jpg");
                                    }

                                    dataGridView1.Visible = false;
                                }


                            }

                            if (!isDataFound)
                            {
                                textBoxEmplNo.Text = "";
                                textBoxWorkNo.Text = "";
                                textBoxName.Text = "";


                                // Display message here that no values found
                                MessageBox.Show("No Result Found");
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        textBoxEmplNo.Text = "";
                        textBoxName.Text = "";

                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to get the files in the specific directory, which has a partial matching names as input value. 
For each directory you are iterating through get the directory info first:

```
 DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
```

Then get the files as mentioned below:

```
FileInfo[] fileInfoArray = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*" + inputFileName + "*.*");
```

Then you can check the fileInfoArray for the file you are looking for. It can return multiple file info, depending on your input.

For reference: added the actual code here:

```
string partialInputName = "12345"; //textbox input value or whatever you want to input
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Code");
        FileInfo fileinDir;
        foreach(string dir in directories)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            if (dirInfo.Exists)
            {
                //taking the first (FirstOrDefault()), considering that all files have a unique name with respect to the input value that you are giving. so it should fetch only one file every time you query
                fileinDir = dirInfo.GetFiles("*" + partialInputName + "*.*").FirstOrDefault(); 
            }               
        }
```

Comment: can you edit in my code? because I already try it but still not work. :(

Comment: For your reference, added the code to iterate through directories and search for file. You can easily integrate with your code.

Answer (score 1):

`File.Exists` looks for one specific file. There is no file with weird name `%'12345%'.jpg` I guess. You can use this form:

```
foreach (var f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootPath, "*12345*.jpg")){
...
}
```

Comment: That just an example. each image is naming like this **Name (employee no.)**

Answer (score 1):

If it's already on the disk just use Directory.GetFiles() like so:

```
var strings = Directory.GetFiles(".","*12345*");

foreach (var s in strings)
{
    Debug.Write(s);
}
```

Comment: can you edit in my code? because I already try it but still not work. :(

Comment: The answer is right there. You should be able to integrate it into the code yourself.

Comment: But I want to search image like this > if user enter at textbox worker no. It will read textbox employee no. to display the image. So, I try like this > `string imgName = "'%" + textBoxEmplNo.Text + "%'" + ".jpg";`. It is wrong if search like that? If I used your way, my way is no need?